# Is there a way to override the unhandled exceptions handler in Titanium Appcelerator?

Tags: titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have noticed that all the unhandled exceptions are handled by Titanium Appcelerator "engine".
Is there any way to prevent this behavior?
Thank you.

Comment: Seems like there is now: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41588529/one-place-to-catch-all-sudden-exceptions-in-titanium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible not even binding with crash reporters natively, they are overriding everything as it seems.

Answer (score -1):

Is there a good reason why you want to do this? The Appcelerator "red screen of death" only shows up during development/in the device simulators (the same exception on an actual iOS device will crash the app). You're best off fixing or catching the exceptions in your app so they're handled appropriately.

Comment: Crashing the app when it encounters an error is hardly "handling" anything, it's just a hack at the platform level, and littering code with try/catch blocks in every function isn't a good way to do exception handling either. Providing a way to catch exceptions globally is an important part of any dev framework, which gives you the option to log the exceptions and show a user-friendly error screen, Titanium not providing this after years of existence is shocking.

Comment: Well said, also they never came back to me and it is not possible to override. Most probably they can't find a way. I've tried with binding and other way back then but nothing happened, we dropped any effort in the platform anyway, old story.